# connection failed! in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working on jupyter notebook.

It was working fine untill I install google-colab.

Now when I run my jupyter-notebook file it shows me an error.

```
Connection failed
A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.
```

In terminal it shows.

```
raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')

RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

[W 20:46:47.278 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed

[W 20:46:47.278 NotebookApp] Kernel d828092a-5424-468c-866c-608a09896ed8 died, removing from 

map.
[W 20:46:53.423 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from d828092a-5424-468c-866c-

608a09896ed8
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: try  `jupyter notebook --no-browser`

Comment: now it not even open.

Comment: it will not open in browser, but it works on command line? it launchs its dependencys?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me:
pip install -U jupyter_console